# SQL Server Data Tools on Azure VM

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, reporting-services

I created a VM using the gallery image, and got SQL server 2014 Standard template and got reporting services working correctly.  My questions here are all about the Azure VM image, which I'm sure the community is using as well (no SSRS in Azure other than using a VM)

ReportBuilder however will not start from a remote client  (401 unauthorized), and I'm sure I have to open another port or something to get it working but I can't seem to find the right article....

I'm also told that SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) is installed on the server, in order to create reports via Visual Studio.  However, I can't seem to find the right link on the server (damn this new Server 2014 interface! hard to loose the muscle memory of the previous os)  What is the start up procedure for SSDT on the VM?

I've also tried using the Browser directly on the VM, but without JavaScript enabled, that wont' work as well.  How do I drop (temp) all the constraints it's under?

In essence, how do you create a report on the Azure VM?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the report server from a browser in a remote client, for example, yourazurevm.cloudapp.net/reportserver, then you have already configured firewall correctly.  Otherwise, refer to this article (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-provision-sql-server/#SSMS) to configure Azure SQL VM.

To create reports using ReportBuilder, install the standalone version of the ReportBuilder 3.0 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6116.  After you launch the ReportBuilder, you can configure it to connect to your Azure SQL report server in the lower left corner.

To create reports using Visual Studio and SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), install SSDT-BI (not just SSDT) in the client where Visual Studio is installed.  Then create a Report Server Project by going to File->New->Project->Installed->Templates->Business Intelligence->Reporting Services. Open the properties of the project, and set the Target Server URL to your Azure SQL report server.